# Printing Python Output on Same Line

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning Python and need my code fixed to produce expected outcome in Python 3.6 , I'm on Windows 10, need to remove trailing comma

My code:

```
food_tuple = ("Cheese", "Olives", "Bread", "Salmon", "Juice")

print ("Old Menu: ")

space = ","

for food in food_tuple:
    print (food, end=space)

food_tuple = ("Cake", "Turkey", "Oats", "Salad", "Juice")

print()
print("New Menu: ")

for food in food_tuple:
    print (food, end=space)
```

Current output:

```
Old Menu: 
Cheese,Olives,Bread,Salmon,Juice,  
New Menu: 
Cake,Turkey,Oats,Salad,Juice,
```

Expected output:

```
Old Menu: 
Cheese,Olives,Bread,Salmon,Juice

New Menu: 
Cake,Turkey,Oats,Salad,Juice
```

Comment: `print(','.join(food_tuple))`?

Comment: what about : `print( ",".join(food_tuple) )` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in two ways

```
food_tuple = ("Cheese", "Olives", "Bread", "Salmon", "Juice")

print ("Old Menu: ")

space = ","

for food in food_tuple: 
    print (food, end=space)

food_tuple = ("Cake", "Turkey", "Oats", "Salad", "Juice")
print()
print("New Menu: ")

for food in food_tuple[:-1]:
    print (food, end=space)
print(food_tuple[-1])
```

or

```
food_tuple = ("Cheese", "Olives", "Bread", "Salmon", "Juice")

print ("Old Menu: ")

space = ","

for food in food_tuple: 
    print (food, end=space)

food_tuple = ("Cake", "Turkey", "Oats", "Salad", "Juice")
print()
print("New Menu: ")


print (','.join(food_tuple))
```

both methods give the required output